# How to create an Action with generic argument?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

example

i have a class

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{

    public interface INode<T>
    {
        T Value { get; }
    }

    public class A
    {
        public void Do1(INode<string> node) { }

        public void Do2<T>(INode<T> node) { }
    }

    public class Programm
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            A a = new A();

            //now I want to pass this method to an another class as arguments

            //it's OK here
            var processor1 = new Proccessor(a.Do1);

            //no idea how to achieve this without making class Proccessor generic type
            var processor2 = new Proccessor(a.Do2);
        }
    }

    public class Proccessor
    {
        //it's OK here
        public Proccessor(Action<INode<string>> do1Action)
        {

        }

        //no idea how to achieve this without making class Proccessor generic type
        public Proccessor(Action<T><INode<T>> do2Action)
        {

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Well what is `TNode`? It's very unclear what you're trying to achieve. Please provide a [mcve] - ideally using just a single type parameter, for clarity. Making it complete is important, as your current example doesn't show where the type parameter is declared...

Comment: You don't really need to do anything special. If you have a method that's sufficiently polymorphic that its type arguments can be instantiated to make it match the required delegate signature, you can just pass it straight in. Simple example: https://www.ideone.com/14awJc

Comment: "no idea how to achieve this without making class Proccessor generic type" - not at all clear what the "this" that you're trying to achieve is! If Processor is to be able to *do anything* with the parameter, it's going to need to know its associated type! And why not make Processor generic, if it has to work with more than one type?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to pass an `Action<T>` to a method such that the method can then choose which `T` to invoke it for. That's simply not possible.

The easiest way around this is avoiding generics entirely, by making all `BaseNodeViewModel<T, U>` derive from a common non-generic `BaseNodeViewModel` type. Your `OnNodeExpanded` then looks like

```
private void OnNodeExpanded(BaseNodeViewModel node) { ... }
```

and it may cast `node` to the concrete type as needed in its implementation.

A more advanced way around this is creating a custom interface type

```
internal interface INodeExpanded {
  void OnNodeExpanded<TNode>(BaseNodeViewModel<TNode, FolderTreeViewModel> node);
}
```

You can then manually create a class which implements this interface, and pass that to `A` instead of a delegate.

Comment: They're not trying to pass an `Action<T>` for some fixed `T`, they're trying to pass a generic method, which is the opposite of the situation you're addressing. A generic method *can* be instantiated to some desired delegate signature when passed where an `Action<SomeFixedType>` is expected.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin C# doesn't let you do that. That's why I started with "[...] That's simply not possible." I then added what C# *does* let you do instead.

Comment: You are wrong about C# not letting you do that. See https://www.ideone.com/14awJc

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin That example does exactly what you say the OP is trying not to do. Instead of taking `Func<T, T>`, it takes `Func<string, string>`, and `GiveMeAStringTransformer`'s implementation can no longer choose whether to invoke `f<string>` or `f<int>` (pseudo-code obviously, since C# doesn't let you do this).

Comment: "They're not trying to **pass** an Action<T> for some **fixed T**". The *argument* is a generic method, the target *parameter* is a fixed type. This corresponds with the OP's question.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin Changed my position from my previous (now deleted) comment: I think you're right about the meaning of the word *argument*. But the question's edit does still convince me the OP wants to be able to generically invoke the *parameter*.

Comment: The OP's question is pretty unclear unfortunately, so that confuses things a lot. The long and short of what I'm saying is: all the types in a method's parameter list are constituted of its own type arguments, its containing type's type arguments, or various concrete types. When a method demands a parameter of a delegate type composed of these three ingredients, you can always pass a *generic* method that has compatible type holes where the parameter's type demands something specific.

Comment: Guys I'll provide a more clear example just a little bit later. sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a generic constructor for a non-generic class. You have at least 3 options (Asad's answer is also very good *if* your intentions are what he specified in his answer):

1. don't use generics. see hvd's answer.
2. make the class generic.
3. don't use T in the constructor, but in another method. You can have a static method that will create and return an instance of the class for you, there you can use the generic action:

```
public class Proccessor
{
    //it's OK here
    public Proccessor(Action<INode<string>> do1Action)
    {

    }

    private Proccessor() 
    {
        // a private constructor for the CreateProcessor static method
    }

    public static Proccessor CreateProccessor<T>(Action<INode<T>> do2Action)
    {
        var proccessor = new Proccessor();
        // invoke action here
    }
}
```

Comment: I think `CreateProccessor<T>(Action<T><INode<T>> do2Action)` is a syntax error. You probably mean `CreateProccessor<T>(Action<INode<T>> do2Action)`

Comment: #Asad good catch. another case of the blessing and curse of the copy n' paste :-)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question depends on what exactly you expect to be able to do with `do2Action` inside the class.

Do you to say "I want to accept and store an action that will be able to work with *any* `INode`"? Assuming that's the case, make `INode` covariant, and demand an `Action<INode<object>>`. Like so:

```
public interface INode<out T>
{
    T Value { get; }
}
```

Then...

```
public Proccessor(Action<INode<object>> do2Action)
{

}
```

Now you can do:

```
var processor2 = new Proccessor((Action<INode<object>>)a.Do2(x));
```

The cast is required to disambiguate from the `string` overload, but if you remove the overloads and instead use distinctly named static methods to construct, you will find that this is type safe.

Note that an immense responsibility has now been pushed to `a.Do2`, it must be able to work with any `INode` whatsoever, without restriction.